# CSS - extend stylesheet styles from a style block

Tags: javascript, css

I need to implement dynamic css styles for certain elements based on a user's role or group identity.

My idea is to fetch the required dynamic values (hex colors, background image urls) from my database, write them to the page, then use jQuery to add styles with these values to the elements that are to be dynamic. Seems straightforward.  Has anyone done it this way?

Another way is to somehow override external style sheet styles with styles defined in a header style block.  Would this work?  Can you share css styles between a style block and an external sheet? Can the shared styles cascade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix internal and external styles. Internal, external, and inline styles all cascade, with inline styles taking precedence over internal styles, which themselves take precedence over external styles.

If you want to dynamically change styles based on user permissions, why not add the relevant classes and id in the body tag, e.g.

`<body id="admin" class="group-1">`

And then use CSS to separate the roles and groups out, e.g.

```
#admin{
    background-color: rgb(255,155,105);
}

.group-1{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.group-2{
    font-family: Roboto;
}
```

You could go one step further and use a CSS pre-processor like LESS to style several groups for individual roles, e.g.

```
#admin {
    background-color: rgb(255, 155, 105);
    .group-1 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .group-2 {
        font-family: Roboto;
    }
}
```

Comment: But can part of the css definition be in a style block in the header, and another part be in an external sheet?  Can a style block "extend" and external css file?

Comment: Yes, they will cascade, with the block (or internal) styles taking precedence over the external styles.